# When chain rule does not apply

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Is it possible for $\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t))$ to exist AND be continuous, but not have it equal to $f'(g(t))g'(t)$, so the chain rule doesn't work?

Assume that $g'(t)$ exists but it may not be continuous. Does chain rule require strictly $C^1$?

I ask because for my example, $f'(g(t))g'(t)$ is not continuous, but $\frac{d}{dt}f(g(t))$ is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule states that if $g$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f$ is differentiable at $g(a)$, then $f \circ g$ is also differentiable at $a$ and $(f \circ g)'(a) = f'(g(a))g'(a)$. So if you assume the derivatives exist, then the chain rule should always hold. The continuity of the derivatives don't matter.

Comment: Suppose $g=f^{-1}\circ h$ and $h$ is $C^1$.  The LHS of the chain rule statement is continuous. The right hand side may not be (I think?). Isn't that problematic?

Comment: Eg. if $f'$ is not continuous.

Comment: Why are you writing $f^{-1}$? Anyway, you only know that $g$ is differentiable since $f^{-1}$ and $h$ are. But how do you know if $g'$ is continuous or not without a specific example?

Comment: Suppose $f^{-1}$ exists.I am fine with differentiability. But I am just saying that $f'(g(a))g'(a)$ may not be continuous, right? Depending on $g'$ and $f'.$

Comment: That's true. But in that case, $(f \circ g)'$ won't be continuous everywhere either so everything works out.